# How Can a Discord Bot reply a different message to different user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm new to coding and have decided to create a Discord bot that sends a different reply each time the bot gets mentioned.

I'm using Discord.js version 13.

Here's the code I have:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.mentions.has(client.user) || message.author.id === "My Discord ID") {
        message.channel.send(`Wassup?`);
    } else {
        if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) {
            message.channel.send(`Holla`);
        }
    }
});
```

Currently, the bot sends only the "Wassup" message when it gets mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to send a random message to the person who tagged you.
for example:

```
const array = ['message_1', 'message_2', 'message_3'];
```

after doing your array messages, you need to do the `Math.random` to get randomly on your `array`

```
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
```

then you can now send it to the person who mentioned you.

```
if (message.mentions.has(client.user)||(message.author.id === "My Discord ID")) {
    message.channel.send(array[random]);
}
```

Whole code:

```
const array = ['message_1', 'message_2', 'message_3'];
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

if (message.mentions.has(client.user)||(message.author.id === "My Discord    ID")) {
    message.channel.send(array[random]);
}
```

I've seen the problem now. Whenever the given id chatting or tagged by itself, the bot will response but not with other members,

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
if(message.author.bot) return
if(message.mentions.users.has("431099770212319232")) {
    const array = ['message_1', 'message_2', 'message_3'];
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    message.channel.send(array[random]);
}
})
```

This will work

[image: Edited]

Comment: it didnt work :<
somehow when i type something, the bot just reply it

Comment: Look at my edited answer now